# Unable to bind WCF service to nodeJS

Tags: node.js, wcf, soap, wsdl, basichttpbinding

I'm trying to bind my wcf service created locally to nodeJs but unable to get the response from below code.

In server.js :

```
 var BasicHttpBinding = require('wcf.js').BasicHttpBinding
          , Proxy = require('wcf.js').Proxy
          , binding = new BasicHttpBinding()
          , proxy = new Proxy(binding, "http://localhost:56986/Service1.svc")
          ,message = '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'+
                          '<s:Header>'+
                          '<Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">"http://localhost:56986/IService/GetData</Action>'+
                          '<s:Header/>'+
                          '<s:Body>'+
                          '<GetData xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">'+
                          '<value>300</value>'+
                          '</GetData>'+
                          '</s:Body>'+
                          '<s:Envelope/>'
        proxy.send(message, "http://localhost:56986/IService/GetData", function(response, ctx) {
          console.log(message)
          console.log(response)
           console.log('done inside');
        });


         console.log('done');

    };
```

WCF service :
[image]

Console output :
[image]

console.log(ctx) Output :
[image]